# Can I Use A Form Field To Rename An Upload Image File?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, image-uploading, buffering

I have an 'Upload-File' field in my form for my site visitors to upload images.

```
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
```

Currently, the file is saved to my server with the same 'name' it was uploaded with.

I would like to add an input field to my form (like the one below) so the user may enter a new 'name' for the [image] file.

```
    <input name="imageRename" id="imageRename">
```

I need some advice on altering the current php code to rename file before it saves to my server.

Here is the current php code for image handling:

```
    <?php 
$target_dir = "articles/article-images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); $uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]); 
    if($check !== false)
    {
        echo "". $check[""].""; $uploadOk = 1;
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "&#xd7; FILE IS NOT AN IMAGE"; $uploadOk = 0;
    } 
}
if(file_exists($target_file))
{
    echo "&#xd7; THIS IMAGE ALREADY EXIST ON SERVER"; $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000)
{
    echo "&#xd7; FILE IS TOO LARGE"; $uploadOk = 0;
}
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" )
{
    echo "&#xd7; ONLY JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF FILES ARE PERMITTED"; $uploadOk = 0; 
}
if ($uploadOk == 0)
{
    echo "&#xd7; IMAGE WAS NOT UPLOADED";
}
else
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
    {
        echo '<img class="fixed-ratio-resize" src="../../articles/article-images/'. basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). '">';
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "&#xd7; IMAGE WAS NOT UPLOADED";
    }
} 
    ?>
```

Comment: If you want to rename your file, use 'move_uploaded_file'. Your target file name '$ target' will be the new name and path where you whant to save the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A example for my comment:

file to upload call image_10.jpg

file name that you whant imag_xpto.jpg

code to change:

```
$target_dir = "articles/article-images/";
$target_new_name = "imag_xpto.jpg";
//your code...
$target = $target_dir.$target_new_name;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
//Your code...
```

If you want a field to give the new name, you only need to create a input field in your html and use this code to get it.

code for post:

HTML:

```
<input type =  "text" name = "inputfieldname">
```

PHP:

```
$target_new_name = $_POST['inputfieldname'];
```

Your code with some tips for debugging and improving Your code

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
     $target_new_name = $_POST["inputfieldname"]; //you can and you should  protect, if you are sending null or empty or undefined it can cause problems in the future. For protect you can use isset and verify if the name it's null or "".
$target_dir = "articles/article-images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); $uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$target_new_file_name =  $target_dir.$target_new_name.".".$imageFileType; // Check with an "error_log($target_new_file_name);" the string "$target_new_file_name". Because it is in the creation of the new string, that the problems occur 
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]); 
    if($check !== false)
    {
        echo "". $check[""].""; $uploadOk = 1;
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "&#xd7; FILE IS NOT AN IMAGE"; $uploadOk = 0;
    } 
}
//if(file_exists($target_file)) - You should now verify that the new file name exists on the server

if(file_exists($target_new_file_name))
{
    echo "&#xd7; THIS IMAGE ALREADY EXIST ON SERVER"; $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000)
{
    echo "&#xd7; FILE IS TOO LARGE"; $uploadOk = 0;
}
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" )
{
    echo "&#xd7; ONLY JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF FILES ARE PERMITTED"; $uploadOk = 0; 
}
if ($uploadOk == 0)
{
    echo "&#xd7; IMAGE WAS NOT UPLOADED";
}
else
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_new_file_name))
    {
        echo '<img class="fixed-ratio-resize" src="'.$target_new_file_name.'">'; // I'm not really sure about this part of the code, I'm used to another type of html creation in php
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "&#xd7; IMAGE WAS NOT UPLOADED";
    }
} 
    ?>
```

I have not had a chance to test so there may be some errors in the code.

Simple way. Any questions, just ask that I will try to answer

Comment: Thank you for your time and suggestion Jose. I tried your code. No luck thus far. I guess perhaps I am still confused as to where exactly your edits/adds should go. Note: The code I included in my post here does work the way I need it to, except for the name change. The rest of it works great. I just want the image file to save with a new name based in the input field in the form. Would it be possible for you to include your edits to achieve that in my full code? Note: Also... to save some trouble... the form text field that will be supplying the new file name is named 'timeValue'.

Comment: If you want that, you need to put your html from your form.

Comment: Here is a stripped down version of the form: <html><form action="ArticleGen.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input name="timeValue" id="timeValue">

<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

<input class="submitButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"></button>

</form></html>

Comment: This way works, but I'm tired because it's already night in my country, so there may be some errors, if you have problems describe the problems you are having, that I will correct the errors at a later time.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me. I will test your edits and see how far I can get. I'll comment back here either way. Thanks again brother. Btw... what country are you in anyway?

Comment: I am from Portugal, the small country that is in the Iberian peninsula. ;)

Comment: @Jamie Sexton Accept the answer if it helped you. This way you are helping people who in the future have the same problem

Comment: Thanks again Jose! The code worked out great! For me particular site, all I had to do was make a minor navigation adjustment: '../../ ' to the directory src echo at the bottom. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should test that the user actually submitted a value for the new name and if not use the original ( or random ). Also - you can use predefined error characteristics found in the $_FILES object to aid processing.

```
<?php 

    $filefield='fileToUpload';
    $textfield='imageRename';

    /*
        function to return the reason for any failure
    */
    function uploaderror( $code ){ 
        switch( $code ) { 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: return "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: return "No file was uploaded"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: return "Missing a temporary folder"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: return "Failed to write file to disk"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: return "File upload stopped by extension"; 
            default: return "Unknown upload error";
        }
    }

    /*
        test that the required items are present in posted data
    */
    if( isset( $_FILES[ $filefield ],$_POST[ $textfield ] ) ){

        $target_dir = "articles/article-images/";
        $errors=array();

        /* set permitted file extensions - not foolproof btw */
        $allowed=array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');

        /* get the properties of the uploaded file */
        $obj=(object)$_FILES[ $filefield ];
        $name=$obj->name;
        $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
        $size=$obj->size;
        $error=$obj->error;
        $type=$obj->type;


        /*
            determine the new name of the file if the user supplied a new name or not
        */
        $newname = !empty( $_POST[ $textfield ] ) ? $_POST[ $textfield ] : false;
        $ext = pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

        $name =( $newname ) ? $newname .= ".{$ext}" : $name;


        /* no errors so far, proceed with logical tests of your own */
        if( $error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){

            if( !in_array( $ext,$allowed ) ) $errors[]="&#xd7; ONLY JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF FILES ARE PERMITTED";
            if( $size > 500000 )$errors[]="&#xd7; FILE IS TOO LARGE";
            if( !getimagesize( $tmp ) )$errors[]="&#xd7; FILE IS NOT AN IMAGE";
            if( !is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) )$errors[]="&#xd7; POSSIBLE FILE UPLOAD ATTACK";


            if( empty( $errors ) ){
                /*
                    set the new file location
                */
                $targetfile = $target_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name;

                /*
                    save the file
                */
                $status = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $targetfile );

                /*
                    determine what to do if it succeeded or not
                */
                if( $status ){
                    echo '<img class="fixed-ratio-resize" src="../../articles/article-images/'. basename( $name ). '" />';
                } else {
                    exit('error');
                }
            } else {/* edited: changed commas to periods */
                exit( '<pre>'.print_r($errors,1).'</pre>' );
            }
        } else {
            exit( uploaderror( $error ) );
        }
    }
?>
```

The above worked fine when I tested this using the form below - the only other difference would be the target directory path which I had set to `c:\temp\fileuploads` for test purposes.

```
    <form id='fileupload' action='/test/so_upload_image_target.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <h1>Upload an image - test</h1>
        <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' />
        <input type='text' name='imageRename' value='boobies' />
        <input type='submit' />
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks Ram. About to test your code. I am assuming where you stated $textfield, I am to replace that with the name of the text field which is supplying the name, yes? Also...  I am getting a syntax error with the line:                  exit( '<pre>',print_r($errors,1),'</pre>' ); But I'll try the code anyway. I'll pop back in right after with feedback.

Comment: Unfortunately, that code did not work. Not only did it not save the image at all.... it also caused my html not to display. The html file did save to its correct folder, but did not display. And the image did not save or display.